# Python: how to concat two dataframes by keeping only constant information?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

```
df1 
     A    B    C    id    val
0    ar    2    3     1    3.2
1    ar    3    3     1    5.6
3    ar    0    3     2    7.8 
4    ar    4    3     2    9.2
5    ar    5    3     2    3.4

df2
     id   val
0     1   3.3
1     2   6.4
```

I want to add a row to `df1` with the information of `df2` and keeping the same value for the columns where the values are constant while `nan` for columns that have different values.

At the end I would like to have

```
df3 
     A    B    C    id    val
0   ar    2    3     1    3.2
1   ar    3    3     1    5.6
3   ar    0    3     2    7.8 
4   ar    4    3     2    9.2
5   ar    5    3     2    3.4
6   ar   nan   3     1    3.3
7   ar   nan   3     2    6.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare first row by all rows for constant columns, so after [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) add them to `df2`:

```
c = df1.iloc[[0], df1.eq(df1.iloc[0]).all().to_numpy()].squeeze()
print (c)
A    1
C    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64


df = pd.concat([df1, df2.assign(**c)], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A    B  C  id  val
0  1  2.0  3   1  3.2
1  1  3.0  3   1  5.6
2  1  0.0  3   2  7.8
3  1  4.0  3   2  9.2
4  1  5.0  3   2  3.4
5  1  NaN  3   1  3.3
6  1  NaN  3   2  6.4
```

Comment: Great: can I do the same for each `id` seperately? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674355/python-how-to-apply-a-function-fo-same-ids-in-a-pandas-dataframe-without-a-loop

Comment: @emax - understand, give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a list of the columns from df1 that have only 1 value using [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), create those in df2, and [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) df1 and df2:

```
eq_cols = []
[eq_cols.append(col) for col in df1.columns if len(np.unique(df1[col]))==1]
df2[eq_cols] = df1[eq_cols]

>>> pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
    A    B  C  id  val
0  ar  2.0  3   1  3.2
1  ar  3.0  3   1  5.6
2  ar  0.0  3   2  7.8
3  ar  4.0  3   2  9.2
4  ar  5.0  3   2  3.4
0  ar  NaN  3   1  3.3
1  ar  NaN  3   2  6.4
```