# Python: how to apply a function fo same ids in a pandas dataframe without a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with same column `id` and for each `id` I need to apply the following function

```
def findConstant(df1,df2):
    c = df1.iloc[[0], df1.eq(df1.iloc[0]).all().to_numpy()].squeeze()
    return pd.concat([df1, df2]).assign(**c).reset_index(drop=True)
```

what I am doing the is the following:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for idx in df1['id']:
    tmp1 = df1[df1['id']==idx]
    tmp2 = df2[df2['id']==idx]
    tmp3 = findConstant(tmp1,tmp2)
    df3 = pd.concat([df3,tmp3], ignore_index(drop=True))
```

I would like to know how to avoid a loop like that

Comment: If you can add some example (with data) to show what exactly you intend to do, it will make it easier to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
print (df1)
     A  B  C  id  val
0   ar  2  8   1  3.2
1   ar  3  7   1  5.6
3  ar1  0  3   2  7.8
4  ar1  4  3   2  9.2
5  ar1  5  3   2  3.4

print (df2)
   id  val
0   1  3.3
1   2  6.4
```

---

```
#get number of unique values and first values to df3
df3 = df1.groupby('id').agg(['nunique','first'])

#filter if same values by comapre by 1
m = df3.xs('nunique', axis=1, level=1).eq(1)

#get correct values to df with replace not matched by original df2
df = df3.xs('first', axis=1, level=1).where(m).combine_first(df2.set_index('id'))
print (df)
      A   B    C  val
id                   
1    ar NaN  NaN  3.3
2   ar1 NaN  3.0  6.4

#join together
df = pd.concat([df1, df.reset_index()], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
     A    B    C  id  val
0   ar  2.0  8.0   1  3.2
1   ar  3.0  7.0   1  5.6
2  ar1  0.0  3.0   2  7.8
3  ar1  4.0  3.0   2  9.2
4  ar1  5.0  3.0   2  3.4
5   ar  NaN  NaN   1  3.3
6  ar1  NaN  3.0   2  6.4
```